# Convert serialized C# DateTime to JS Date object

Tags: c#, javascript, json, serialization

How can I convert that date format `/Date(1302589032000+0400)/` to JS Date object?

Comment: you have `/Date(1302589032000+0400)/` as string?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remove the text first:

```
var src = "/Date(1302589032000+0400)/";

//Remove all non-numeric (except the plus)
src = src.replace(/[^0-9 +]/g, ''); 

//Create date
var myDate = new Date(parseInt(src));
```

[Here's a workding jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SJTAv/5/)

Comment: Won't this loose the timezone/offset info?  `parseInt` stips the `+0400`.  Isn't `+0400` important?