# Fixing JSON Date serialization from .Net web method

Tags: c#, ajax, entity-framework, serialization, webforms

I am currently working on a project where I am sending a .Net type via ajax to a client application via ajax.  I have no issues with the object being serialized and set to the client.

I run into issues when I take the exactly same object and post it back to the server via a web method with the following error: `/Date(1373950800000)/ is not a valid value for DateTime.`  Which is pretty annoying as that is how Microsoft gave it to me, but that's besides the point.

Does anyone have a quick fix for this?  I want a seamless way this can be accomplished without having to change the object right before returning it from the ajax call.

Comment: Which serializer are you using on the server-side?

Comment: Do you get the string `/Date(1373950800000)/` from the server? Or just `1373950800000`?

Comment: did a search and found this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928281/convert-serialized-c-sharp-datetime-to-js-date-object
Hopefully this will help :)

Comment: @KarlAnderson The default on that ASP.NET 4.0 uses

Comment: @HanletEscaño The server literally returns `/Date(1373950800000)/` after json serialization.

Comment: @MattBodily The post is helpful but doesn't help because I don't want to have to have the client convert it because of Microsoft's own serializer can't deserialize it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue comes down to the server-side JavaScript serializer you are using; either `JsonDataContractSerializer` (default serializer for ASP.NET MVC) or `NewtonSoft Json Serializer` (default serializer for ASP.NET Web API).

For a visual example of this date mangling issue as well as possible solutions, check out [JSON Dates are Different in ASP.NET MVC and Web API](http://www.devcurry.com/2013/04/json-dates-are-different-in-aspnet-mvc.html#.Ufvl1Y3VD6Q).

Comment: I am using ASP.NET webforms 4.0.  A requirement of the project.

Comment: The linked to webpage uses javascript to overcome the problem. Not to solve the fact that a suboptimal serializer is in use.

Answer (score 7):

Handle the DateFormat while serialization
following code will resolve your problem

```
   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourobject, Formatting.Indented,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                         DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
                    });
```

It will result the dates in 2009-02-15T00:00:00Z format

Comment: Note for those that are trying this, JsonConvert is the NewtonSoft.Json, not the .NET Json, so you have to install that using NuGet (or other methods).  See the Linked and Related questions for more information.

Comment: With this solution, you can create web methods that returns strings, but I still want to return objects. By returning an object hierarchy, google chromes devtools still can create a treeview of the returned data.

Answer (score 2):

This one will help you with the error: [click me](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net.aspx)

```
var yourDateTimeObject = ...
var converter = new IsoDateTimeConverter();

string isoDateTime = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourDateTimeObject, converter);
```

Comment: The issue I have with this is that I am manually serializing it rather than letting .NET handle it. I want to keep the same `DateTime` type in .NET without having to do my own trickery to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that I use for these things:

First you need to clean the junk out of the date parameter

```
String unixDate = "/Date(1373950800000)/";
unixDate = unixDate.Replace("/Date(","").Replace(")/", "");
```

Now, as .NET and unix measure time in a different way, you have to compensate for that by creating a date set to the 1st of Jan 1970 and then adding the numeric part of the date that you were passed

```
DateTime dotNetDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
dotNetDate = dotNetDate.AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToInt64(unixDate)
```

You should also note that there will a loss of precision here - .NET dates are to the nearest nanosecond where unix dates are to the nearest millisecond

Comment: This solution will only work for retrieval (read: `GET` request) of the date, if you try to set (read: `POST` request) the date, then you will run into the same issue, because the serializer being used on the server-side will mangle the date.

Comment: @KarlAnderson - Could you elaborate more with an example of how the date looks after a post? I've not come across this

Comment: CurlyPaul - it is not how the date looks after the POST, it will be fine then, the problem occurs when the serializer tries to convert the value back to a .NET date; it will be mangled. See the link in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try sending the dates with the forward slashes escaped.  I have an iPad client that posts JSON to an ASP.NET WebAPI service method and we have to send dates this way:

`"due": "\/Date(1335830400000)\/"`

Comment: I'm not very keen on forcing the client to make a change to the serialized information coming straight from the server right after it gets it...EDIT: I tried is and same error.

Comment: From what I've seen, the server also sends the dates with forward slashes escaped.  When I've called my service methods using Fiddler, I see dates as `"\/Date(1334938675734)\/"`.

Comment: Javascript automatically strips the backslashes, but I forced the string literal of `\/Date(1334938675734)\/` and it still failed with the same error.