# using Json ATTRIBUTE to serialize datetime to look like /Date(1486516302715) in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datetime

```
class className 
{ 
    Datetime dateTime {get; set;} 
}
className object = new className();
```

When I use Json(object) this returns the dateTime field in this format :
{"dateTime":"/Date(1486516302715)/"}

But what I want is to return the same value using an attribute to the dateTime parameter instead.

Something like :

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
Datetime dateTime {get; set;}
```

Only the JavaScriptDateTimeConverter is not the one which gives me the date in the right format.

Comment: Check out [JSON Dates are Different in ASP.NET MVC and Web API](http://www.devcurry.com/2013/04/json-dates-are-different-in-aspnet-mvc.html#.Ufvl1Y3VD6Q) and [Fixing JSON Date serialization from .Net web method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38498141/6741868)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you could use the new Date method.

```
new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6))); // date= "/Date(1486516302715)/"
```

Comment: I am trying to look for something in C# and need something to be added a a property for the item so it reads as datetime everytime and reads as the string only when the object is json converted. ... class className 
{ [JsonConverter(typeof(???))]
    Datetime dateTime {get; set;} 
}